# How to store either std::string or std::string_view in a std::variant?

Tags: c++, c++20, stdstring, string-view, std-variant

I am working on a lexer. I have a `Token` struct, which looks like this:

```cpp
struct Token {
    enum class Type { ... };
    
    Type type;
    std::string_view lexeme;
}
```

The `Token`'s `lexeme` is just a view to a small piece of the full source code (which, by the way, is also `std::string_view`).

The problem is that I need to re-map special characters (for instance, `'\n'`). Storing them as-is isn't a nice solution.

I've tried replacing `lexeme`'s type with `std::variant<std::string, std::string_view>`, but it has quickly become spaghetti code, as every time I want to read the lexeme (for example, to check if the type is `Bool` and lexeme is `"true"`) it's a big pain.

Storing `lexeme` as an owning string won't solve the problem.

By the way, I use C++20; maybe there is a nice solution for it?

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ does not have a reputation for being nice. There can be various solutions to this, but they would be highly context-dependent, and tailored to the rest of the code.

Comment: As `std::string` and `std::string_view` have similar interface, it seems that `std::visit` code would be simple...

Comment: Please show an example where `std::variant<std::string, std::string_view>` is causing you trouble. Assuming the owning/non-owning combination works out for your use case, I don't see why this should result in particularly convoluted code. Of course working with `std::variant` is far from being as nice as in languages with proper sum types.

Comment: Is using `std::string_view` here worth the pain, in terms of performance (and maybe memory overhead, as well as, effectively, risk of dangling pointers)?  Maybe SSO (short string optimisation) will come to your aid.

Comment: I would solve this in another way: *always* have both a `std::string_view` *and* an `std::string`. The string_view can point to the original source text or the Token's own `std::string`; the ` std::string`  in the Token is empty if unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You could just use `std::string`

Firstly, a `std::string` could be used in a `Token` just as well as a `std::string_view`. This might not be as costly as you think, because `std::string` in all C++ standard libraries has SSOs (small string optimizations).

This means that short tokens like `"const"` wouldn't be allocated on the heap; the characters would be stored directly inside the container. Before bothering with `std::string_view` and `std::variant`, you might want to measure whether allocations are even being a performance issue. Otherwise, this is a case of premature optimization.

#### If you insist on `std::variant` ...

User @Homer512 has provided a solid solution already. Rather than using the `std::variant` directly, you could create a wrapper around it which provides a string-like interface for both `std::string` and `std::string_view`.

This is easy to do, because the name and meaning of most member functions is identical for both classes. That also makes them easy to use through [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

```cpp
struct MaybeOwningString
{
    using variant_type = std::variant<std::string, std::string_view>;
    using size_type = std::string_view::size_type;

    variant_type v;

    // main member function which grants access to either alternative as a view
    std::string_view view() const noexcept {
        return std::visit([](const auto& str) -> std::string_view {
            return str;
        }, v);
    }

    // various helper functions which expose commonly used member functions
    bool empty() const noexcept {
        // helper functions can be implemented with std::visit, but this is verbose
        return std::visit([](const auto& str) {
            return str.empty();
        }, v);
    }

    size_type size() const noexcept {
        // helper functions can also be implemented by using view()
        return view().size();
    }

    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that all you need is to encapsulate the variant to provide a uniform interface to both. Since it is dirt-cheap to convert an `std::string` to an `std::string_view` and it is equally cheap to copy an `std::string_view`, you can just create a method for that and access the content like that.

```cpp
struct OptOwnString
{
    using variant_t = std::variant<std::string, std::string_view>;
    variant_t value;

    std::string_view view() const noexcept
    {
        /**
         * Note: noexcept since it is effectively impossible to
         * make this particular variant valueless_by_exception
         */
        return std::visit([](auto const& v) {
              return std::string_view(v); }, value);
    }
};

int main()
{
    OptOwnString owning { std::string("foo") };
    std::cout << owning.view() << '\n';
    OptOwnString borrowed { owning.view() };
    std::cout << borrowed.view() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `view()` could be `const noexcept`, and to reduce emitted code size, you could use `*std::get_if<std::string_view>(value)`.

Comment: Or, much shorter implementation of `view` (which is also more resilient to future changes): `return std::visit([](auto const& v) { return std::string_view(v); }, value);` Which, if you happen to have a function object lying around that does `static_cast`, can read much nicer: `std::visit(static_cast_<std::string_view>, value)`